# meteor account-facebook package

Tags: node.js, facebook, meteor, facebook-access-token

I am using account-facebook package for my meteor application. I used my facebook personal clientid and appid and the authencation works.

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
    service: 'facebook'
});

ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
    service: 'facebook',
    appId: '123456789',
    secret: 'secretid'
});
```

But it is only working for my personal facebook account as i have entered its clientid and appid.

Here is the error i am getting when log in with different account.

[image]

How could i make it to work for every facebook account? Means any user can log in into my application with his/her fb account.

Answer (score 1):

you have to go to your developers page on facebook, click on the app review option on the left side of the screen. Then you will see an option of "make *yourAppName* public?". If the option is set to "no", you are going to see the message "your app is in development and unavailable to the public." So you have to switch it to "yes".

Answer (score 0):

On the Facebook developers page, select your app and

1. On the settings page, make sure you've added your contact email, and
2. On the Status and Review page, click the features-available-to-the-general-public slider to "YES".

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I can not see "status and review page". Only options available are dashboard,settings,app details,roles,open graph and canvas payment.

Comment: I'm registered as a Facebook developer, but I just use it for OAuth. Perhaps that has something to do with it. I'm not sure what makes certain options available on the sidebar nav...

Answer (score 0):

I create two applications - production and test. Then I check if Meteor.absoluteUrl() is localhost and set up FB service accordingly:

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
  service: "facebook"
});

if (/localhost/.test(Meteor.absoluteUrl())) {
  ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
    service: "facebook",
    appId: "testAppId",
    secret: "testAppSecret"
  });
} else {
  ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
    service: "facebook",
    appId: "productionAppId",
    secret: "productionAppSecret"
  });
}
```

Also setup your Site URL in app *Settings* and make sure your app is public in *Status & Review*.